# Consume Secured Web API using Indy in Delphi 7, XE2 & 10.1

Tags: delphi, https, openssl, delphi-7, indy

We have 3 different projects developed in Delphi 7, XE2 & 10.1. We are trying to consume the Secured Web API from those application using Indy component. While doing so, I was getting **"Could not load SSL library.”** error.

Versions of Indy for Delphi 10.1, XE2 & 7 are : 10.6.2.5341, 10.5.8.0, and 9.00.10 respectively.

I have downloaded latest **ssleay32.dll** & **libeay32.dll** (openssl-1.0.2l-i386-win32). That helped me to get rid of this issue from Delphi 10.1 & XE2. But I am still facing this **"Could not load SSL library.”** issue for Delphi 7 having Indy 9.00.10.

So I tried below things,

1. Get compatible **ssleay32.dll** & **libeay32.dll** from somewhere - I am unable to find the compatible DLLs.
2. Few forums suggest that I need to upgrade Delphi 7 Indy component to Indy 10. - I have done that and upgraded to Indy 10.6.2. Now I expect latest **ssleay32.dll** & **libeay32.dll** (openssl-1.0.2l-i386-win32) should work here. but it is not.
3. Last alternative was to develop a DLL in Delphi 10.1 to consume Secured Web API and load that from Delphi 7. This is working fine. But that is the workaround.

Now I am looking solution for #1 & #2 above.

1. Where can I find Indy 9.00.10 (Delphi 7) compatible **ssleay32.dll** & **libeay32.dll** files?
2. After upgrade to Indy 10.6.2 on Delphi 7, Where can I find compatible **ssleay32.dll** & **libeay32.dll** files?

Comment: You can find SSL libs here: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Comment: I tried.. but even oldest version is not working in this case. I have downloaded latest version from this site only and it is working for Delphi 10.1 and XE2.

Comment: Indy 9 does not support official OpenSSL DLLs at all. It requires custom OpenSSL 0.9.6 DLLs that have extra Indy-specific exports added to them. Those DLLs are available at http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive. Only Indy 10 can use the official OpenSSL DLLs. The latest Indy 10.6.2(.5434) supports the latest OpenSSL 1.0.2l DLLs, so if you are still having a problem after upgrading, you need to explain exactly what that problem is.